# Is there any way to set the initial count record number for google drive files just like setMaxResults?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

```
service.files().list().setMaxResults(50)
```

Just like the above one is there any way to set the initial count or is it possible through query?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  What do you mean by initial count.

Comment: I mean starting record number,lets say if there are 200 records I want it form 20 to 40.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have a request that will return 200 files.

By setting maxResults to 20 you will return 20 files per page and you will end up with 10 pages.  You can then use pageToken to request the rest of the files.

```
Files.List request = service.files().list().setMaxResults(20);

    do {
      try {
        FileList files = request.execute();

        result.addAll(files.getItems());
        request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
        request.setPageToken(null);
      }
    } while (request.getPageToken() != null &&
             request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
```

You have to make the main request then set go though each of the pages.   There is no way to say make a request that will return 200 files and then only get files 101 - 120.

**Note** I am not a java programmer that example was copied from the documentation [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list)

Answer (score 0):

@daimTo has the correct answer. A couple of additional points...

1/ "you will end up with 10 pages", actually you will end up with **at least** 10 pages, as some may be sparsely populated.

2/ The best way to achieve the effect the OP is looking for is to:-

1. Do an initial request for 20, specifying "fields=nextPageToken, items/id".
2. Verify that there are 20 items in the result. If not, subtract the count from 20 and repeat step 1 with the difference. Repeat until 20 have been fetched.
3. Do your query with whatever maxResults you are looking for, again 20 in the example given. As with step 2, be aware that you aren't guaranteed to get 20 in a single page, so you must monitor nextPageToken.

Of course, if the numbers are really 20-40, it would actually be much quicker just to request 40 and ignore the first 20 items in the result set.